# Writing matrix on binary file C

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I am working in C with some binary files using the famous commands fwrite/fread.
I have to write pairs of numbers, one pair per line, like this:

```
double values[2];
for (int i=0 ; i<numPairs ; i++){
    values[0]=rand();
    values[1]=rand();
    fwrite(&values, sizeof(double), 2, myFile);
}
```

where `myFile` is (as its name suggests) a file I've opened using `fopen()`.

Although I’ve got a couple of questions:

1. in a binary file it is possible to write 2 numbers on the same line?
2. if so, will this command do the trick? I've been scavenging around for answers but I wasn't able to find something that confirms this point. It's ok with arrays and such, but for matrices...?

Comment: There are no lines in binary files.

Comment: @RadLexus, so there's only one massive column, am I right?

Comment: There is no notion of lines, row, or columns in a binary file. It's just a blob of bits and bytes.

Comment: You need to clarify why you think in terms of "lines" and "columns". It's unclear because you don't have a "matrix" type of structure.

Comment: @RadLexus, well, to me "lines" and "columns" are my rows and columns of such matrix where a single row is a given pair (of rands() in this code snippet). I know I can format nicely with fprintf/fscanf, although I have such pairs that I must generate and then I have to work with them (i.e. sort the rows) and I was hoping to save such matrix in a nice format.

Comment: Non-portable file format and maybe unnecessarily hard to debug (In binary files, *you* need to know what is where - It's just bits. But works.

Comment: @user6079603 Well that's up to your program. Two numbers will be on the same "line" if your program says they're on the same "line". The file doesn't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary file does not have a concept of "lines" - it's entirely up to your program.

Currently you write `numPairs*2` `double`s to the file, two at a time. You could equally well each `double` individually, or store them all in an array and wrote them all with one call to `fwrite`.

Likewise, the reading program is free to read them individually, or two at a time, or all at once.

Comment: That is indeed a great hint. I was able to tackle the problem by setting the appropriate `typedef` and `fread()` and `fwrite()` combo. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean text file, since binary files don't have columns or rows just 1's and 0's which is only readable for computers

Comment: What is your question ?